# Make the Like button understand separated pages

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I run a multiple author Wordpress platform where authors post articles where many of them are separated in several pages. The visitors can navigate the pages within the article by clicking on a `Next` button. This is various types of articles like galleries, lengthy articles, lists etc

I am sure you are all familiar with the Next button by now. The issue here is that the Facebook like button cannot detect that it is **one** article and treats it as completely separate pages.

This is the **valid** XHTML 1.0 code I use for the Like button:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode("http://domain.com" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=300&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border-style:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode("http://domain.com" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=300&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" style="border-style:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;">
</iframe>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The IE conditions are there so that it works correctly in IE8.

The URL of the articles are like this. The original first page is:

```
http://domain.com/title-of-the-article/
```

And the second page is:

```
http://domain.com/title-of-the-article/2/
```

And so on... **How do I make it so that the Like button detects the second page as the first (original) page and avoid separating them as different**? I have googled this all day and must have found at least 50 different programmers asking this with no solution so clearly there are others that are hoping for an answer.

Comment: Set the main URL in your Open Graph meta tags.

Comment: Can you kindly explain in detail how I do that?

Comment: Change your `og:url` meta tag on the 'sub' pages to all point at the main URL for the article

Comment: Sorry I am unfamiliar how exactly I would do this? Note that I am running Wordpress. Would it be through some type of filter or hook? More info please...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you replace this code of yours `<?php echo urlencode("http://domain.com" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>` into `<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>` or specify the post/page id as parameter `<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>`. So the code must look like this

```
  //make sure to declare the global $post variable
  global $post;
  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=300&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" style="border-style:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;">
```

```
 //or with id specified
 global $post;
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=300&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" style="border-style:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;">
```

Even if the page is in any page number it'll still render the original page permalink. The fb like button would treat the page into another different page because the permalink is different.